# Titanium ios notification suddenly stopped working

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, titanium-mobile

Push notifications for my ios titanium app has suddenly stopped working. It was working fine before 2-3 weeks ago but it's not working now. Request to notification getting submitted successfully. I had push notifications all nicely set up for our iOS app, but they stopped working a few weeks ago. It looks like our requests are sent to APNS ok, but push notifications are not being received. I am getting follow response to my request.

{
  "meta": {
    "status": "ok",
    "code": 200,
    "method_name": "NotifyTokens"
  }
}

But I am getting no notification to my or any device. Any idea???

Comment: What about your push notification certificate? Have you checked it's expiry date?

Comment: @Anand Thanks buddy it works. It was a certificate problem.

Comment: @Prasanth: You're welcome. If your issue has been solved, please answer to your own question how you resolved the issue. may be it can help some one else :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem. It was a .p12 certificate problem. I generated new certificate and used it for my application and it worked.